# Java GUI and actions

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a problem.

I have been out of the game for a while and was given a side project for a friend. He has asked me to create a GUI that has a search bar, a button and a label.

He has asked me that when the user types in something, and presses enter, the results must be displayed in the table below.

So I fired up Netbeans and got to work using the drag and drop support to begin the creation of the GUI.

Then I got stuck. What I need help with is to figure out how to tie it together.

This is what I have so far:

```
package video.store;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame{

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        super("Films & Series");
        setSize(300, 120);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        lbMovie = new JLabel("Enter movie name: ");
        txField = new JTextField();
        bSearch = new JButton("Search");
        tblList = new JTable();
        setVisible(true);
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        lbMovie = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        bSearch = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tblList = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        lbMovie.setText("Enter Move Name: ");

        txField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        bSearch.setText("Search");
        bSearch.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                bSearchActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        tblList.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tblList);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lbMovie)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(txField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 167, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(bSearch, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 104, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lbMovie)
                    .addComponent(txField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(bSearch))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(40, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    }                                       

    private void bSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    }                                       

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=master;user=Brandon;password=Brandon1");
                    System.out.println("Connection successful");
                } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                    System.out.println("SQL Exception" + sqle);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error" + e);
                }
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton bSearch;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbMovie;
    private javax.swing.JTable tblList;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txField;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Where are you "stuck"?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: And note: the editor or IDE you are using doesnt matter at all. There is no point in using the netbeans tag here.

Comment: Question not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to attach a keylistener to the text field

```
KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
          printIt("Pressed", keyEvent);
      }

      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
          printIt("Released", keyEvent);
      }

     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
          printIt("Typed", keyEvent);
     }

     private void printIt(String title, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
         int keyCode = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
         String keyText = KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode);
         System.out.println(title + " : " + keyText + " / " + 
             keyEvent.getKeyChar());
     }
};
txField.addKeyListener(keyListener);
```

You can also use a change listener to detect changes to the text in the textfield

Also just to let you know, JavaFX is the replacement from Swing. Swing is no longer supported but it should still work just fine. FYI

Comment: Ah, that's what it was. Thanks for that. Really helped

Comment: Sure no problem, could you help mark the answer as the "best" answer is you feel it deserves it?